# Two versions of android support-v4

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I'm trying to import [actionbarcherlok](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) project inside my project (actionbarsherlok is a project marked with "is library")
My project includes yet `support-v4 library`, so when I import sherlock action bar (that also includes support-v4 library) I obtains the following error:

```
 Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
 but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
```

That means I have to remove one library.

I have removed the `support-v4 library` that was already in my project, but I obratin an error at this line

```
public class ReminderCreation extends FragmentActivity{
```

because FragmentActivity was taken from support-v4 library:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

I can I solve this problem? Can I refer to the support-v4 library included in the sherlock project?

**NOTE:**

I have also tryied changing `FramentActivity` into `SherlokFragmentactivity`, obtaining this error:

```
The hierarchy of the type ReminderCreation is inconsistent.
```

**EDIT:**

If I introduce this modification (suggested by @ascorbin) and I otain this error at runtime:

```
10-17 09:30:12.190: E/dalvikvm(1877): Could not find class 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder', referenced from method host.framework.ApplicationFramework.onCreate
10-17 09:30:12.190: W/dalvikvm(1877): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 489 (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder;) in Lhost/framework/ApplicationFramework;
10-17 09:30:12.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 09:30:12.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1877): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder
```

at this line:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

inside a class that extends `Application`

(I have never get this error before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error didn't mean that you had to delete one support-jar but that they all have to be the same version. Delete the support library from both projects, then right-click -> android -> add support library for both, then they'll both have the same jar.

Comment: uhm, ok @Ascorbin. Do you thin is better add for both the support library that resides in \libs directory of the Main project?

Comment: @Ascorbin please change "right-click -> android-> add support library" to "right-click -> android tools -> add support library "